# how to get the nearest Int floored from a sqrt of an Int?

Tags: swift

I need the largest int at or below the sqrt of n.

I am getting *Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'sqrt' returns immutable value*

```
func isPrime (n:Int) ->  Bool {
    if n < 2 { return false }

    generatePrimes(to: sqrt(Double(n)).round(.towardZero))
```

The same problem with `.squareRoot`

How can I generate to:Int here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call generatePrimes with a Double

```
generatePrimes(to: floor(sqrt(Double(n)))
```

or if you want to call it with an Int

```
generatePrimes(to: Int(floor(sqrt(Double(n))))
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two different methods in the [FloatingPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint) protocol:

```
mutating func round(_ rule: FloatingPointRoundingRule)
func rounded(_ rule: FloatingPointRoundingRule) -> Self
```

The first one mutates the receiver, and the second one returns a new value. You want to use the second one:

```
sqrt(Double(n)).rounded(.towardZero)
```

or

```
Double(n).squareRoot().rounded(.towardZero)
```

But if you need the result as an integer then it is simply

```
Int(Double(n).squareRoot())
```

because the conversion from `Double` to `Int` already *truncates*
the result towards zero.